# How to track select menu discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to create a code that will create the required number of menu selects and then respond to them after clicking. I create my menu select like this

```js
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  select.addOptions([
    {
      label: `${i}`,
      value: `value${i}`,
      description: `${i} role`
    }
  ])
}
```

Where `arr.length` - required number of selects. I just can't figure out how to get the value on this select menu. I'd be happy to even have a hint! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`select.addOptions()` takes in an Array of options, so you could do it this way:

```
let selectarr = [];
for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    selectarr.push({
        label: `{i}`,
        description: `value${i}`,
        value: `${i} role`,
    });
}

select.addOptions(selectarr)
```

The comment:

```
//Create select menu const select = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents( new StringSelectMenuBuilder() .setCustomId("your id") 
.setPlaceholder("Your palceholder") 
.addOptions(selectarr) ); 
//Reply 
const sendResult = interaction.channel.send({ content: "Your text", embeds: [if you have an embed], components: [select], });
```

Comment: Yes, this method will also work, but how in the future should I answer this select menu? Because I don't know `i`

Comment: you would reply to an interaction or send in a specific channel. I do know your usercase/code for a specific answer

Comment: Reply to the interaction. In standart code I use this - `if(interaction.values[0] == customId)`, but this I don't know how to get value (from cycle `for`)

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do, This is how I reply in my case:

//Create select menu
     const select = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
      new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
       .setCustomId("your id")
       .setPlaceholder("Your palceholder")
       .addOptions(selectarr)
     );
//Reply
      const sendResult = interaction.channel.send({
                                                        content: "Your text",
       embeds: [if you have an embed],
       components: [select],
      });

Comment: Yeah, but I want to sent if the user chose select action 1, send 1, if 2 - 2 ... . In this case, I just can't figure out how to get value(custom Id) of option select menu
Because in collect or interactionCreate I must know this information. yes, I know the the custom id of ALL select menu, but don't know of special menu

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, but I think there is a more reasonable solution to my problem, I give you my version

```js
const select = new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
  .setCustomId(`newTest`)
  .setMaxValues(1)
  .setPlaceholder(`Placeholder`) // create the select menu

const clearArr = [] // add to array the number of select interaction
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  clearArr.push(i)
  select.addOptions([
    {
      label: `${i}`,
      value: `value${i}`,
      description: `${i} role`,
    }
  ]) // add selet menu
}

const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
  .addComponents(select) // add all components with cycle for

let sendmsg = await message.channel.send(); // your message, need to discord.js collector
const collector = sendmsg.createMessageComponentCollector({
  componentType: ComponentType.StringSelect, 
}); // create select menu collector
collector.on("collect", async (collected) => {
  const value = collected.values[0]; // first value in collector
  for (const check of mas) {
    if (value == `value${check}`) {
      message.channel.send(`hi`)
    }
  }
});
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help :)

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.